# undefined method `load_defaults' on rails generate migration and rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-generators

I'm getting this error when I run: `rails generate migration AddRoleToBuyer role:integer`

The error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000055e8c09a10d8> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/config/application.rb:24:in `<class:Application>'
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/config/application.rb:22:in `<module:ApiService>'
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/config/application.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /home/murilo/projects/api-service/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

The application and rspec tests is running with no problems, but migrations not working.

EDIT: this is happening when I run `rails console` too.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails 5.1.6, ruby 2.5.1p57. Are thinking if it's conflict between versions?

Comment: What is output of `rails -v`?

Comment: @Vasfed Rails 5.1.6

Comment: Try `spring stop` and cleaning bootsnap cache in tmp/cache

Comment: @Vasfed I did this, but the problem remains. :(

Comment: So you have table /model Buyers/ Buyer ?

Comment: @Nezir yes, I have the model Buyer inside a module Account. This can make a difference?

Comment: and you have Buyers table also?

Comment: Just a suggestion: googling your error gives problems related to missing or messing with configurations e.g (change Gem.rb manually or the Schema.rb). As the problem seems to be with the ActiveRecord "side", try to review your updates on the seed, schema etc, configurations related to database. We will need more information to help.

Comment: @PedroGabrielLima not sure if it is ActiveRecord side because the rails console doesn't work either.

Comment: Rails console loads ActiveRecord when starts. Do you can save/update or delete data in you app? What exactly works in you app? Everything? When this kind of error happens, usually is something you did a few minutes before. What was the last things you were working on?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L65     - look what the method load_defaults does. It loads module Active* base on your rails version.